# How to autowire service with implicit ExecutionContext argument

Tags: java, spring, scala

In a Scala project I work on we have an API that early on imports a global execution context like this

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

I later create a UserStorageService that requires said execution context. I'm attempting to introduce Spring Annotations into my application, but I'm getting stuck on how to handle the execution context. How do I autowire an implicit variable? I've tried this

```
class UserStorageService(
  @Qualifier("userdb") val databaseConnector: DatabaseConnector
)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends UserStorageTable {
```

that I'm trying to get as

```
private val userStorageService = appContext.getBean(classOf[UserStorageService])
```

resulting in

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

import this:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext;
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext$;
```

and in your configuration(`@Configuration`) add this

```
@Bean
public ExecutionContext getExecutionContext() {
    return ExecutionContext$.MODULE$.global();
}
```

And `ExecutionContext` bean will be added to the Spring context.